# Get the correct product object type from an Id in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am inputing a meta box into the product page in the Admin section of woocomerce.

Inside this box I need to check the current product type to create my code around said type.

Somehow, only in this setup I'm getting incorrect results, elsewhere I can do the same code and correct data is returned. I've tested in an own admin page or even display the type in the front end.. all perfect. Just the admin product page am I getting this anomaly..

All CMS and plugins are tripled check to be up to date.

The code is simple:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'reboot_add_meta_boxes' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'reboot_add_meta_boxes' ) )
{
    function reboot_add_meta_boxes()
    {
    add_meta_box( 'reboot_custom_testbox', __('Test Box','woocommerce'), 'reboot_custom_testbox_function', 'product', 'advanced', 'core' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'reboot_custom_testbox_function' ) )
{
    function reboot_custom_testbox_function()
    {
        global $post;
        $RebootProduct = new WC_Product( $post->ID );
        $RebootMessage = '';
        if( $RebootProduct->get_type() == 'simple' ){
            $RebootMessage = 'This is a simple Product <br>';
        } elseif( $RebootProduct->get_type() == 'variable' ){
            $RebootMessage = 'This is a Variable Product <br>';
        } else{
            $RebootMessage = $RebootProduct->get_type();
        }
        echo $RebootMessage;
        return;
    }
}
```

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change from: new WC_Product( $post->ID ); to wc_get_product( $post->ID );
So you have

```
$RebootProduct = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
```

Comment: Thanks.. yeah that helped !